# Spring boot application and concurrency issues

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-boot

I am developing an application that will run under spring boot context with tomcat. This project connects on startup to Kafka, pulls messages and process them. The tomcat is used for some management APIs.

When Spring is loading, it connects with Kafka by several threads.
Each thread is autowired with a spring bean that handles a message. This bean of-course autowired with more beans etc..

Do I need to consider concurrency issues? Synchronize stuff? use concurrent types such as ConcurrentHashMap instead of normal HashMap for example?

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spring, the bean is singleton by default. The methods of bean can be called by several threads in concurrently. In every method, you don't need to care about concurrency. But if you want to save the data in some other places, like bean members of other data object, you should care about the concurrency for those data holder.

In this example:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
   public Map handle(Map dataHolder) {...}
}

@Service
public class OtherSerice {
  @Inject SomeService serv1;
  Map theDataNotSafe = new HashMap();

  public Map func() {
    Map theData = new HashMap();
    serv1.handle(theData); // thread safe, 
    serv1.handle(theDataNotSafe); // not thread safe
  }
}
```

The OtherService.func() function will call `SomeService.handle(..)`. Function `serv1.handle(theDataNotSafe);`  is not thread safe, because there are several threads will call the function with the same `HashMap`.

Comment: So If I create a new HashMap (not concurrent) and pass it through the beans without using any private members, I'm OK?

Answer (score 4):

There are not enough details.

> Each thread is autowired with a spring bean that handles a message

Ok, are bean's functions thread safe? If they already are or (which is equivalent) the bean is stateless you don't have to explicitly synchronize it. 

If you use library solutions for fetching and deserializing messages than this thread-safe issues are usually mentioned in docs.

You pull messages in several threads, but do you process received messages in place or by another worker(-s)? If you have additional workers for processing than you have to safely pass message to them using thread-safe collection (e.g. [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) )

> ConcurrentHashMap instead of normal HashMap for example?

If your bean stores fetched messages into map which is an not local but instance variable, so different threads write and read to/from it, than this actions should be synchronized. Using ConcurrentHashMap is a good way in this case.